# RDP into corporate laptop which is VPN connected to another network

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

Here is my scenario: -

I have a personal laptop ('L#P') and a work laptop ('L#W'). Both run windows OS.
To access company resources, etc., I need to connect to their VPN.
I need to use Pulse Secure VPN and connect to their specific server. I can't use split tunneling or something like that, cuz the VPN looks like it was made in the 1900s as we only have the ability to connect to the specified servers. That's all. I guess the company set it that way for security or whatever...

Both 'L#P' and 'L#W' are connected to the same network (via my mobile hotspot).
Without VPN, I am able to RDP into 'L#W' from 'L#P'.

But then when 'L#W' is connected to VPN, The connection gets dropped. What can I do to continue using RDP when 'L#W' is connected to the VPN?

Comment: The company's 1990's era VPN has policies that could be considered good security practices in the 2020's. If you were able to RDP into L#W when it is connect to the VPN then all security provided by the VPN would be bypassed. You'd essentially be opening up a new gateway into the VPN'ed network that is not under control of the network administrators. Very bad idea.

Comment: Pretty much guessed so. Which means there is no way to bypass it. Lol, my personal laptop is better and larger than the corporate one, so I would prefer RDP, but I guess that won't be possible anymore.